# How to dynamically allocate arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, new-operator

I know how to dynamically allocate space for an array in C. It can be done as follows:

```
L = (int*)malloc(mid*sizeof(int));
```

and the memory can be released by:

```
free(L);
```

**How do I achieve the equivalent in C++?**

Specifically, how do I use the `new` and `delete[]` keywords? Especially in the context of creating/destroying a linked list node, or creating and destroying an array whose size is given by a variable during compile time?

Comment: I highly suggest looking at the index (or table of contents) of your C++ reference for "new" or "operator new" or "dynamic memory".  Any good reference should tell how to allocate and deallocate memory.

Comment: Here's a plethora of [StackOverflow Articles on memory allocation for C++](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+c%2B%2B+allocate+memory+new&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).

Comment: For lazy searching, I have used [Google for c++ dynamic memory example](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+example+dynamic+memory&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).

Answer (score 37):

```
int* L = new int[mid]; 
delete[] L;
```

for arrays (which is what you want) or

```
int* L = new int;   
delete L;
```

for single elements.

But it's more simple to use vector, or use smartpointers, then you don't have to worry about memory management.

```
std::vector<int> L(mid);
```

`L.data()` gives you access to the `int[]` array buffer and you can `L.resize()` the vector later.

```
auto L = std::make_unique<int[]>(mid);
```

`L.get()` gives you a pointer to the `int[]` array.

Answer (score 10):

Following Info will be useful : 
Source : https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/6-9a-dynamically-allocating-arrays/

**Initializing dynamically allocated arrays**

If you want to initialize a dynamically allocated array to 0, the syntax is quite simple:

```
int *array = new int[length]();
```

Prior to C++11, there was no easy way to initialize a dynamic array to a non-zero value (initializer lists only worked for fixed arrays). This means you had to loop through the array and assign element values explicitly.

```
int *array = new int[5];
array[0] = 9;
array[1] = 7;
array[2] = 5;
array[3] = 3;
array[4] = 1;
```

Super annoying!

However, starting with C++11, it’s now possible to initialize dynamic arrays using initializer lists!

```
int fixedArray[5] = { 9, 7, 5, 3, 1 }; // initialize a fixed array in C++03
int *array = new int[5] { 9, 7, 5, 3, 1 }; // initialize a dynamic array in C++11
```

Note that this syntax has no operator= between the array length and the initializer list.

For consistency, in C++11, fixed arrays can also be initialized using uniform initialization:

```
int fixedArray[5] { 9, 7, 5, 3, 1 }; // initialize a fixed array in C++11
char fixedArray[14] { "Hello, world!" }; // initialize a fixed array in C++11
```

One caveat, in C++11 you can not initialize a dynamically allocated char array from a C-style string:

```
char *array = new char[14] { "Hello, world!" }; // doesn't work in C++11
```

If you have a need to do this, dynamically allocate a std::string instead (or allocate your char array and then strcpy the string in).

Also note that dynamic arrays must be declared with an explicit length:

```
int fixedArray[] {1, 2, 3}; // okay: implicit array size for fixed arrays

int *dynamicArray1 = new int[] {1, 2, 3}; // not okay: implicit size for dynamic arrays

int *dynamicArray2 = new int[3] {1, 2, 3}; // okay: explicit size for dynamic arrays
```

Comment: How can do this with multidimensional arrays?

Comment: Same as C. Allocate an outer array, then iterate over the elements, and for each one, assign an inner array.  Or `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`. or `std::vector<std::array<int, 3>>` if you know the size of the inner arrays.

Answer (score 4):

you allocate memory using the `new` operator and release a pointer using `delete` operator. Note that you can't delete normal variables, only pointers and arrays can be deleted after accomplishing their task.

```
int * foo;
foo = new int [5];
delete[] foo;
```

a complete program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <new>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  int i,n;
  int * p;
  cout << "How many numbers would you like to type? ";
  cin >> i;
  p= new (nothrow) int[i];
  if (p == nullptr)
    cout << "Error: memory could not be allocated";
  else
  {
    for (n=0; n<i; n++)
    {
      cout << "Enter number: ";
      cin >> p[n];
    }
    cout << "You have entered: ";
    for (n=0; n<i; n++)
      cout << p[n] << ", ";
    delete[] p;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

result

```
How many numbers would you like to type? 5
Enter number : 75
Enter number : 436
Enter number : 1067
Enter number : 8
Enter number : 32
You have entered: 75, 436, 1067, 8, 32,
```

Answer (score 2):

In C++ we have the methods to allocate and de-allocate dynamic memory.The variables can be allocated dynamically by using `new` operator as,

```cpp
type_name *variable_name = new type_name;
```

The arrays are nothing but just the collection of contiguous memory locations, Hence, we can dynamically allocate arrays in C++ as,

```cpp
type_name *array_name = new type_name[SIZE];
```

and you can just use `delete` for freeing up the dynamically allocated space, as follows,
for variables,

```cpp
delete variable_name;
```

for arrays,

```cpp
delete[] array_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to be extremely careful when using raw pointers with dynamic memory but here is a simple example.

```
int main() {
    // Normal Pointer To Type
    int* pX = nullptr;
    pX = new int;
    *pX = 3;

    std::cout << *pX << std::endl;

    // Clean Up Memory
    delete pX;
    pX = nullptr;

    // Pointer To Array
    int* pXA = nullptr;
    pXA = new int[10]; // 40 Bytes on 32bit - Not Initialized All Values Have Garbage
    pXA = new int[10](0); // 40 Bytes on 32bit - All Values Initialized To 0.

    // Clean Up Memory To An Array Of Pointers.
    delete [] pXA;
    pXA = nullptr;

    return 0;     

} // main
```

To avoid memory leaks; dangling pointers, deleting memory to early etc. Try using smart pointers. They come in two varieties: shared and unique.

**SomeClass.h**

```
#ifndef SOME_CLASS_H
#define SOME_CLASS_H

class SomeClass {
private:
    int m_x;

public:
    SomeClass();
    explicit SomeClass( x = 0 );

    void setX( int x );
    int  getX() const;

private:
    SomeClass( const SomeClass& c ); // Not Implemented - Copy Constructor
    SomeClass& operator=( const SomeClass& c ); Not Implemented - Overloaded Operator=
};  // SomeClass

#endif // SOME_CLASS_H
```

**SomeClass.cpp**

```
#include "SomeClass.h"

// SomeClass() - Default Constructor
SomeClass::SomeClass() :
m_x( x ) {
} // SomeClass

// SomeClass() - Constructor With Default Parameter
SomeClass::SomeClass( int x ) :
m_x( x ) {
} // SomeClass

// setX()
void SomeClass::setX( int x ) {
    m_x = x;
} // setX

// getX()
void SomeClass::getX() const {
    return m_x;
} // getX
```

**Old Way Of Using Dynamic Memory**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SomeClass.h"

int main() {
    // Single Dynamic Pointer
    SomeClass* pSomeClass = nullptr;

    pSomeClass = new SomeClass( 5 );

    std::cout << pSomeClass->getX() << std::endl;

    delete pSomeClass;
    pSomeClass = nullptr;

    // Dynamic Array 
    SomeClass* pSomeClasses = nullptr;
    pSomeClasses = new SomeClasses[5](); // Default Constructor Called


    for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
        pSomeClasses[i]->setX( i * 10 );
        std::cout << pSomeSomeClasses[i]->getX() << std::endl;
    }

    delete[] pSomeClasses;
    pSomeClasses = nullptr;  

    return 0;
} // main
```

The problem here is knowing when, where and why to delete memory; knowing who is responsible. If you delete the memory to manage it and the user of your code or library assumes you didn't and they delete it there is a problem since the same memory is trying to be deleted twice. If you leave it up to the user to delete it and they assumed you did and they don't you have a problem and there is a memory leak. This is where the use of smart pointers come in handy.

**Smart Pointer Version**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include "SomeClass.h"

int main() {
    // SHARED POINTERS
    // Shared Pointers Are Used When Different Resources Need To Use The Same Memory Block
    // There Are Different Methods To Create And Initialize Shared Pointers
    auto sp1 = std::make_shared<SomeClass>( 10 );

    std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> sp2( new SomeClass( 15 ) );

    std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> sp3;
    sp3 = std::make_shared<SomeClass>( 20 );

    std::cout << "SP1: " << sp1->getX() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "SP2: " << sp2->getX() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "SP3: " << sp3->getX() << std::endl;

    // Now If you Reach The Return Of Main; These Smart Pointers Will Decrement
    // Their Reference Count & When It Reaches 0; Its Destructor Should Be
    // Called Freeing All Memory. This Is Safe, But Not Guaranteed. You Can
    // Release & Reset The Memory Your Self.

    sp1.reset();  
    sp1 = nullptr;

    sp2.reset();
    sp2 = nullptr;

    sp3.reset();
    sp3 = nullptr;

    // Need An Array Of Objects In Dynamic Memory?
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SomeClass>> vSomeClasses;
    vSomeClasses.push_back( std::make_shared<SomeClass>( 2 ) );
    vSomeClasses.push_back( std::make_shared<SomeClass>( 4 ) );
    vSomeClasses.push_back( std::make_shared<SomeClass>( 6 ) );

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SomeClass>> vSomeClasses2;    
    vSomeClasses2.push_back( std::shared_ptr<SomeClass>( new SomeClass( 3 ) ) );
    vSomeClasses2.push_back( std::shared_ptr<SomeClass>( new SomeClass( 5 ) ) );
    vSomeClasses2.push_back( std::shared_ptr<SomeClass>( new SomeClass( 7 ) ) );

    // UNIQUE POINTERS
    // Unique Pointers Are Used When Only One Resource Has Sole Ownership.
    // The Syntax Is The Same For Unique Pointers As For Shared Just Replace
    // std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> with std::unique_ptr<SomeClass> &
    // replace std::make_shared<SomeClass> with std::make_unique<SomeClass>
    // As For Release Memory It Is Basically The Same
    // The One Difference With Unique Is That It Has A Release Method Where Shared Does Not.

    auto mp1 = std::make_unique<SomeClass>( 3 );
    mp1.release();
    mp1.reset();
    mp1 = nullptr;

    // Now You Can Also Do This:
    // Create A Unique Pointer To An Array Of 5 Integers
    auto p = make_unique<int[]>( 5 );

    // Initialize The Array
    for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
        p[i] = i;
    }

    return 0;
} // main
```

Here Are Reference Links To Both Shared & Unique Pointers

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh279669.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh279676.aspx