# I can't understand how to use size_t in C++

Tags: c++, size-t

When I have to use size_t, can I use such expressions?

```
/* size_ is size_t type and has some value*/
```

and I want to change the value like
`++size_;`
or `--size_;`

And I also want to make array using size_t
like

```
array[size_]=something;
```

Are they valid?

Comment: `size_t` is an unsigned integer type, so all of them are valid.

Comment: Is this what you're asking? [How to dynamically allocate arrays in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35532427/how-to-dynamically-allocate-arrays-in-c)

Comment: `array[size_]=something;` assigns to an array element, it doesn't create a new array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use all of them because `size_t` is an unsigned integer type.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    size_t size_ = 0;
    int array[10] = {0};
    int something = 42;

    std::cout << "initial: " << size_ << std::endl;

    ++size_;

    std::cout << "incremented: " << size_ << std::endl;

    --size_;

    std::cout << "decremented: " << size_ << std::endl;

    array[size_]=something;

    std::cout << "array: " << array[0] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```