# error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript in array

Tags: c++, arrays

This is my code, what am I doing wrong with it?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int a[n];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) cin >> a[i];

    for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (a[i] > j[i]) cout << a[i] << " ";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting an error:

> error: invalid types for array subscript

Comment: Hmmm `int a[n];` looks invalid for C++.

Comment: You are comparing `a[i]` to `j[i]`.  The latter is a typo, you certainly meant `a[j]`.

Answer (score 0):

> ```cpp
> int n;
> cin >> n;
> int a[n];
> ```

This is creating a **Variable-Length Array**, which is [not standard C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/), but some compilers allow it as a non-standard extension.  That, in of itself, is not an error, but it is something to be avoided.  Use `std::vector` instead when you need a dynamically-allocated array.

That said, your error is here:

> ```cpp
> if (a[i] > j[i]) cout << a[i] << " ";
> ```

`j` is an `int`, you can't index into it.  You need to use `a[j]` instead of `j[i]`:

```
if (a[i] > a[j]) cout << a[i] << " ";
```

Answer (score 0):

The int array's subscript must be a constant number if you initalizing a array.
If you want to using a dynamic array,you can use the int pointer just like this:

```
int n;
//Make some changes...
int *buffer=new int[n];
```

Comment: `std::vector<int>` would be even better. `operator new` is easy to teach, but pointers are hard to use.

Answer (score -1):

I believe your problem is in line 3 of main:
`int a[n];`
For dynamically allocating arrays in c you might want to take a look at this post: [How to dynamically allocate arrays in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35532427/how-to-dynamically-allocate-arrays-in-c)

Comment: That is a semantic error (in C++, maybe not with his compiler) but it is not the error the question is about.