# Head pointer not accessible when creating a method for hashing chaining

Tags: c++, class, pointers, hash, linked-list

I am creating a method for chaining using a linked list, here I declare 3 classes namely node, LL(linked list), chaining, I am not able to handle
here in the chaining class, I am dynamically creating an array of pointer to a linked list, and using the class LL, I am setting my head pointer of a linked list to null, but the program is not able to access it and I got a segmentation fault. By debugging, I found the faulty line, that is as follows:

`cout<<this->head;`

I will also highlight in code

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class node{
    public:
    int data;
    int index;
    node* next;
};
class LL{
    public:
    node* head = NULL;
    void InsertForChaining(int data,int i){
        cout<<this->head;// faulty line 
        if(!head){// faulty line
            node *t = new node;
            t->data = data;
            t->index = i;
            t->next = NULL;
            head = t;
            t = NULL;
        }
        else{
            node *p = head;
            node* r;
            while(p || data<p->data){
                r = p;
                p = p->next;
            }
            node *t = new node;
            t->data = data;
            t->index = i;
            t->next = NULL;
            r->next = t;
            t = NULL;
            r = NULL;
        }
    }
};
class Chaining{
    public:
    LL **arr;
    int n;
    Chaining(vector<int>&nums){
        n = nums.size();
        arr = new LL*[n];
        for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
            int storage = nums[i]%n;
            arr[storage]->InsertForChaining(nums[i],i);
        }
    }
    int search(int key){
        node* p = arr[key%n]->head;
        while(p){
            if(p->data == key){
                return p->index;
            }
            p = p->next;
        }
        return -1;
    }
};
int main(void){
    vector<int>v1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    cout<<"hello start"<<endl;
    Chaining c1(v1);
    cout<<"hello"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have an `int index;` member? That isn't necessary for forward chaining or normal hash-table function.

Comment: I am using it to get the index of key in original array or vector defined in main function and passed to chaining function as it is the original index of that key in given array

Comment: Okay, see also [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/3422102) and [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/364696)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are essentially trying to code the beginning of a hash-table using `arr` as your hash-table and then using *Forward-Chaining* to handle any collisions. In your case since you have `n` unique values using your hash of `nums[i] % n` and `n` buckets, you will not have any collisions so you will have a 1-node list at each of the `arr[i]` locations.

To begin with since `class LL` contains the `node *head` member, you do not need to declare and allocate pointers and then nodes with `LL **arr;` you simply need to allocate for `LL *arr;` allocating one instance of `class LL` for each bucket as your hash-table. Then `InsertForChaining()` will allocate and insert a new `head` node each time chaining any existing nodes. You do that as:

```
    Chaining (std::vector<int>&nums) {
        n = nums.size();
        arr = new LL[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int storage = nums[i] % n;
            arr[storage].InsertForChaining (nums[i], i);
        }
    }
```

You are drastically over-complicating how you do *Forward-Chaining*. Your `InsertForChaining()` reduces to:

```
class LL {
    public:
    node *head = NULL;
    void InsertForChaining (int data,int i) {
        node *t = new node;
        t->data = data;
        t->index = i;
        t->next = head;
        head = t;
    }
};
```

When you write a class that allocates with `new`, makes sure you write a destructor to `delete` the memory you have allocated, otherwise you will leak memory. A simple destructor is all that is needed, e.g.

```
    ~Chaining() {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            while (arr[i].head) {
                node *victim = arr[i].head;
                arr[i].head = arr[i].head->next;
                delete victim;
            }
        }
        delete[] arr;
        arr = nullptr;
    }
```

(**note:** how in each of the functions the removal of the one level of indirection to accommodate the change of `LL **arr` to `LL *arr`.)

Your `search()` function need only iterate until it finds the node with `data` matching `key`. If you reach the end of the list before `key` is matched, then you return your `-1`. That reduces `search()` to:

```
    int search (int key) {
        node *p = arr[key%n].head;
        
        while (p && p->data != key)
            p = p->next;
        
        return p ? p->index : -1;
    }
```

You can add a short function to output the contents of your hash-table to confirm the stored values. Just loop over each bucket and iterate from `arr[i].head` until `nullptr` is reached. That can be done with:

```
    void prnlist () {
        std::cout.put ('\n');
        
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            node *t = arr[i].head;
            std::cout << "arr[" << i << "]:";
            while (t) {
                std::cout << " (" << t->data << ", " << t->index << ")";
                t = t->next;
            }
            std::cout.put ('\n');
        }
    }
```

Whenever you write functionality into your code, you should test it with short unit tests. In `main()` simply print the table and search for each value in your vector to ensure it is found in your table. Only produce output from your tests if an error occurs. For example:

```
int main(void) {
    
    std::vector<int>v1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    std::cout << "hello start\n";
    
    Chaining c1(v1);
    c1.prnlist();
    
    std::cout << "\nvalidating search of each value.\n";
    for (const auto i : v1)
        if (c1.search(i) == -1)
            std::cerr << "error: " << i << " not found in table.\n";
    std::cout << "(validation done)\n";
    
    std::cout << "\nhello\n";
}
```

You will want to read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/3422102) and [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/364696). Building good habits early is easier than breaking bad ones later...

Another little nit is there is no need to output a string literal and then `endl`, e.g.

```
    cout<<"hello start"<<endl;
```

Instead, simply include `'\n'` as part of the string literal, e.g.

```
    std::cout << "hello start\n";
```

Putting it altogether, you could do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class node {
    public:
    int data;
    int index;
    node *next;
};

class LL {
    public:
    node *head = nullptr;
    void InsertForChaining (int data,int i) {
        node *t = new node;
        t->data = data;
        t->index = i;
        t->next = head;
        head = t;
    }
};

class Chaining {
    public:
    LL *arr;
    int n;
    Chaining (std::vector<int>&nums) {
        n = nums.size();
        arr = new LL[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int storage = nums[i] % n;
            arr[storage].InsertForChaining (nums[i], i);
        }
    }
    ~Chaining() {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            while (arr[i].head) {
                node *victim = arr[i].head;
                arr[i].head = arr[i].head->next;
                delete victim;
            }
        }
        delete[] arr;
        arr = nullptr;
    }
    void prnlist () {
        std::cout.put ('\n');
        
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            node *t = arr[i].head;
            std::cout << "arr[" << i << "]:";
            while (t) {
                std::cout << " (" << t->data << ", " << t->index << ")";
                t = t->next;
            }
            std::cout.put ('\n');
        }
    }
    int search (int key) {
        node *p = arr[key%n].head;
        
        while (p && p->data != key)
            p = p->next;
        
        return p ? p->index : -1;
    }
};

int main(void) {
    
    std::vector<int>v1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    std::cout << "hello start\n";
    
    Chaining c1(v1);
    c1.prnlist();
    
    std::cout << "\nvalidating search of each value.\n";
    for (const auto i : v1)
        if (c1.search(i) == -1)
            std::cerr << "error: " << i << " not found in table.\n";
    std::cout << "(validation done)\n";
    
    std::cout << "\nhello\n";
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/chaining_vector
hello start

arr[0]: (9, 8)
arr[1]: (1, 0)
arr[2]: (2, 1)
arr[3]: (3, 2)
arr[4]: (4, 3)
arr[5]: (5, 4)
arr[6]: (6, 5)
arr[7]: (7, 6)
arr[8]: (8, 7)

validating search of each value.
(validation done)

hello
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to ensure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/chaining_vector
==15924== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==15924== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==15924== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==15924== Command: ./bin/chaining_vector
==15924==
hello start

arr[0]: (9, 8)
arr[1]: (1, 0)
arr[2]: (2, 1)
arr[3]: (3, 2)
arr[4]: (4, 3)
arr[5]: (5, 4)
arr[6]: (6, 5)
arr[7]: (7, 6)
arr[8]: (8, 7)

validating search of each value.
(validation done)

hello
==15924==
==15924== HEAP SUMMARY:
==15924==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15924==   total heap usage: 13 allocs, 13 frees, 73,980 bytes allocated
==15924==
==15924== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==15924==
==15924== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==15924== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

You have two bugs:

Number one in **line 47** where you dynamically create your linked list class. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35532427/how-to-dynamically-allocate-arrays-in-c) post as reference.

```cpp
arr = new LL*[n]; // <-- This needs to change
*arr = new LL [n]; // <-- To this
```

You get the *segmentation fault* because you are trying to access memory that has not been allocated correctly. In your case you are only creating `LL*` pointers and not instances.

Secondly,

In **line 27**, you check the contents of the `p->data` in the same line where you check if `p` is nullptr:

```cpp
while (p || data < p->data) { // Cannot check null p->data
```

This will also result in a *segmentation fault* when you reach the end of the list.

With the first proposed solution and the removal of the second check in your while statement, the output of your program is now:

```
hello start
00x8230900x8230900x8230900x8230900x8230900x8230900x8230900x823090hello

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: `while (p || data < p->data)` is 100% correct. If the first condition fails, the second is never reached.

Comment: What valid memory address was provided to `arr` before you do `*arr = new LL [n];`? Without changing more `*arr` dereferences the pointer `arr` while the address it holds is indeterminate.

Comment: thanks everyone for helping me out, and Thanks David for those worthy suggestions , I learned a lot today

Comment: while (p || data < p->data) this will 100% fail because I used or operator here instead of and operator, in case of and operator , the condition will be 100% correct